# AngularJS: ngRoute Not Working

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am tying to get this simple routing to work and can't figure out what is the problem.

This is the HTML:

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
     .
     .
     .  
     <a href="#voip">
       <div class="col-lg-3 service">
        <img src="assets/img/voip.svg"/>
        <h4 ng-bind-html="content.home.voip_header"></h4>
        <p ng-bind-html="content.home.voip_txt"></p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <section id="view">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </section>
```

This is the routing:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[
  'ngRoute',
  'ngSanitize'
]);
    app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
      .when('/voip',{
        templateUrl:'assets/templates/voip.html'
      });
    }]);
```

The template is loaded if I specify 'otherwise' as below. I thought maybe I am using the wrong syntax in my href attribute, but I looked everywhere and seems like this is how it should be.

```js
      .otherwise({
       redirectTo:'/voip'
      })
```

Another thing is, if I listen to `$routeChangeSuccess`, the event is triggered, yet the view is not loaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Are you loading this page from a server as opposed to `file/open` in browser?

Comment: Angular version is 1.6.1. Yes, pages are loaded from the server, at the moment this is a local apache with no configuration change, just for serving files.

Comment: I just want to state that the code you displayed has no errors in the provided question context.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's properly because you are using angular 1.6 and there has been a change the default hash-prefix:

> Due to aa077e8, the default hash-prefix used for $location hash-bang
>   URLs has changed from the empty string ('') to the bang ('!'). If your
>   application does not use HTML5 mode or is being run on browsers that
>   do not support HTML5 mode, and you have not specified your own
>   hash-prefix then client side URLs will now contain a ! prefix. For
>   example, rather than mydomain.com/#/a/b/c the URL will become
>   mydomain.com/#!/a/b/c.
>
> If you actually want to have no hash-prefix, then you can restore the
>   previous behavior by adding a configuration block to you application:
>
> appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
>   $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); }]); [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8)

So you have some options:

**1. Set HTML5mode true**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and in html set base in html header:

```
<base href="/">
```

Lastly change `<a ng-href="#voip">` to

```
<a ng-href="voip">
```

**2. Use the 1.6 way** 
Change 
 `<a ng-href="#voip">` 

to 
 `<a ng-href="#!voip">`

**3. Go back to old behaviour from 1.5 - set hash prefix manually**

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

Comment: So is [the example in the docs for $route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) broken? It seems to use option 1, but never sets a base tag. How would one ever figure out any of these options by just looking at these docs? It's frustrating when the example in the docs isn't done right... I went with option 2, and it seems to work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try to use exclamation marks in html5 + ajs 1.6.

for example instead of href="#home"..... write href="#!home".
It worked for me after 4 hours of head scratching.

Answer (score 0):

5 and I figured out why it wasn't working earlier

I missed to include following in index.html

```
 <div ng-view></div>
```