# Simple AngularJS routing not working properly

Tags: angularjs, routes

For some reason, I can't seem to route to the `add` screen.  What am I doing wrong?  Here's my `app.js`

```
var moviesApp = angular.module('moviesApp', ['ngRoute']);

moviesApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'MoviesController'
        })
        .when('/add', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/add.html',
            controller: 'MoviesController'
        })
        .when('/edit', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/edit.html',
            controller: 'MoviesController'
        });
});
```

Here's the anchor tag:

```
<a href="#add">Add Movie</a>
```

Which is contained within my `home.html` template which is a part of `index.html`.

The app doesn't crash...it just doesn't do anything.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you implemented `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` then you can use it like this `<a href="/add">Add Movie</a>` otherwise try this `<a href="#/add">Add Movie</a>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be because of the change in the default hash-prefix in angularjs version 1.6. What you have written works in the given context: [Proof](https://plnkr.co/edit/iOaBlGcFGtVwcPnDhHN6?p=preview)

You can confirm this is the case by changing:

```
<a href="#add">Add Movie</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="#!add">Add Movie</a>
```

If it works look at for possible solutions at:

[AngularJS: ngRoute Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655831/6682369)

If you want to make i behave as you expect (version 1.5) you could choose soultion 3 from the link:


**3. Go back to old behaviour from 1.5 - set hash prefix manually**

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

set up a route start event to help debug the problem

```
.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(current);
        console.log(next);
        console.log('$routeChangeStart: ' + next.originalPath)
    });
});
```

just add this to the end of your route config

Just as a side note I would use a state provider over a route provider.  State providers let you define a hierarchy.  It's a little harder to work with but much more flexible.