# angularjs routing tutorial bug not routing

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-1.6

I just created a simple project to learn angular routing, my project is the following:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="#/">Home</a>
        <a href="#/hi">Hi</a>
        <a href="#/bye">bye</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ng-view"></div>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**scripts.js:**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "home.html"
    })
    .when("/hi", {
        templateUrl: "hi.html"
    })
    .when("/bye", {
        templateUrl: "bye.html"
    });
});
```

**hi.html:** `<h1>Hi</h1>`

**bye.html:** `<h1>bye</h1>`

**home.html:** `<h1>Home</h1>`

The three html from above only contains a h1 tag to keep it simple

A plunker of my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/uNZicTuRKDkR7ATwdFE0

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Dunno if outdated or why its not working, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using angular 1.6 and the toturial is using 1.4. Your links should be like this because of the new hash prefix in version 1.6:

```
  <div>
    <a ng-href="#!/">Home</a>
    <a ng-href="#!/hi">Hi</a>
    <a ng-href="#!/bye">bye</a>
  </div>
```

See plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/qUYYcFjfwi9kEGxa7zOu?p=preview

Read more about what else to do at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655831/6682369

Comment: lol, thanks I thought it was a kind of bug, seems to be that almost all the tutorials out are using angular 1.4, Thank you very much :D