# ngRoute not working - AngularJS 1.6.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do a `Route` in AngularJS 1.6.6, but I don't realize why it's not working.
I have searched for every post here about this subject, but I didn't find the answer.

I am trying to run this on `WAMP` local server. So far, everything worked, except when I started using `ngRoute`.

**It's not the same problem that I have found (like this [angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working)) because I am not trying to click in a link to reach out the main.html, but so only to load this inside the index.html as a main content (the first content to be displayed).**

app.js

```
angular.module('warmup', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider){

    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix(''); => this is something that I tried...

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateURL: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'BoardController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

});
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>AngularJS - Warmup</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="warmup">

    <!-- PLEASE SEE, THERE IS NOT ANY LINK HERE -->
    <!-- content -->
    <div class="container">
       <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="scripts/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/board/board-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

main.html (the template)

```
 <div id="content">
    <div ng-style="boardStyle" class="board">
      <div ng-repeat="tile in getNumber(tiles) track by $index" 
        ng-click="changeToggle($index)" ng-init="initToggle($index)" 
        ng-model="status[$index]" ng-style="style($index)"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <nav id="sideNav">
    <h3>Controls</h3>
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
      <a ng-href="#" ng-click="startSelect()" id="start" class="button">Start</a>
      <a ng-href="#" ng-click="endSelect()" id="end" class="button">End</a>
      <a href="#" id="go" class="button not-active">GO!</a>
      <hr>
      <div class="settings"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

BoardController.js

```
angular.module('warmup').controller('BoardController', function($scope) {

    /* Tiles variables and functions */

    var size = 12;
    $scope.tiles = [];

    $scope.tiles = size * size;
    $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);   
    }
    //Get the coordinates in a bi-dimensional array
    _positionToCoordinates = function($index) {
        var x = $index % size,
            y = ($index - x) / size;
        // return [
        //   x, y
        // ];
        return {
            x: x,
            y: y
        };
      };

    $scope.status = [];

    /* Styles functions */

    var boardHeight = window.innerHeight/3;
    var boardWidth = boardHeight;

    var tileHeight = boardHeight/12 - .3;
    var tileWidth = tileHeight;

    $scope.boardStyle = {
        "height" : boardHeight + 'px',
        "width" : boardWidth + 'px',
        "border" : "1px solid #AAA"
    }
    // Colors array => it will be dynamic
    var colors = [
        {name: "main", color: "white"},
        {name: "locker", color: "black"}, 
        {name: "start", color: "green"},
        {name: "end", color: "blue"},
        {name: "path", color: "yellow"}
    ];
    $scope.style = function ($index) {       
        return {
            "height" : tileHeight + 'px',
            "width" : tileWidth + 'px',
            "border" : "1px solid #CCC",
            "background-color": colors[$scope.status[$index]].color,
            "float": "left"
        }
    }

    /* Events */

    var isStartSelected = false;
    var isEndSelected = false;

    $scope.initToggle = function($index) {
      $scope.status[$index] = 0;
    }

    $scope.changeToggle = function($index) {
        if (isStartSelected) {
            for (var i in $scope.status) {
                if ($scope.status[i] === 2) {
                    $scope.status[i] = 0;
                }
            }
            $scope.status[$index] = 2;
            console.log($scope.status[$index]);
            console.log(_positionToCoordinates($index));
        }else if (isEndSelected) {
            for (var i in $scope.status) {
                if ($scope.status[i] === 3) {
                    $scope.status[i] = 0;
                }
            }
            $scope.status[$index] = 3;
            console.log($scope.status[$index]);
            console.log(_positionToCoordinates($index));
        } else {
            // $scope.status[$index] = 0 ? 0 : 1;
            $scope.status[$index] = ($scope.status[$index] === 0 ? 1 : 0);
            console.log($scope.status[$index]);
        }
    }

    $scope.startSelect = function(){
        isStartSelected = true;
        isEndSelected = false;
        console.log("click start");       
    }

    $scope.endSelect = function(){
        isEndSelected = true;
        isStartSelected = false;
        console.log("click end");        
    }


  });
```

The application doesn't display any error, and all of assets load ok. But I only see a blank page instead:
[image]

When I inspect the page, I see my `<ng-view>` only as a comment in the html.

If I move the main.html content in place of `<ng-view>`, write the `ng-controller="BoardController"` inside of `<div class="container">` (in index.html) and I comment the routes on app.js, everything works (that means there is no error in my Controller, I think):
[image]

Comment: What is the full path of `main.html`

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: The full path is http://localhost/ICV/views/main.html

Comment: No, no errors in console...

Comment: Are you sure the controller is executing itself ? tried logging something in that BoardController ?

Comment: @BlackBurn027 If I move the main.html content inside of index.html (no route), the BoardController works perfectly and I don't have any error. I suppose that there is a problem in route, no?

Comment: possibly... share the route and controller definition code also it might help.

Comment: @BlackBurn027 I added some other informations. Pls, say to me if I missed something.

Comment: Try putting the line `<script src="scripts/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>` before `<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>`, it might be a load order issue since app.js depends on the router.

Comment: @Andrew Heys it's not working yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some changes to ng-route library from v1.6 
Please see detailed answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655831/6347317

Referencing another answer as well,  that I gave: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45808238/6347317

Please try referencing your routes with "#!route".

**Edit** : Ignore above answer. The solution seems to be pretty simple.
There is a typo. "templateURL" should be "templateUrl" . :)

```
 $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateURL: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'BoardController'
    })
```

should be:

```
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'BoardController'
    })
```

Comment: I am not trying to click in some link to reach out this main.html page. This page should be load as the first page (as a filling inside the index.html). Is it not the same, right?

Comment: Wow, and I spend hours with it! Thanks a lot!