# AngularJS relative url's not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url-routing

Trying to use relative url's for my single-page angularjs app, but can't get either the page to load with any styling, or to load with angular working.

JS:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider    
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController as main'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController as main'
    })
    .when('/newPayroll', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/newPayroll.html',
        controller: 'newPayrollController as newPayroll'
    })
    .when('/employeesList', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/employeesList.html',
        controller: 'employeesListController as employeeList'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}])
```

When I add the base tag to the top of the head like this it renders the page without styling, and page links don't work:

```
<base href="/" />
```

And when I add it like this the styling works, but angular stops working completely, even though no errors show in the console, and clicking on links takes me to a file index screen:

```
<base href="./" />
```

File structure:

```
'dashboard' folder
app.js
index.html
'pages' folder
    home.html
    page2.html
    etc...
'js' folder
    angular.js
'css' folder
    style.css
```

Comment: have you tried removing the leading / from your routes? 'pages/home.html' That should work

Comment: Doesn't make a difference unfortunately

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Errors saying the external scripts/stylesheets couldn't load when no dot present before slash in base tag, but none when dot added before it

Comment: How are you refrencing these in HTML? From angularjs 1.6+, there is a change . Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655831/6347317